# retrieving top-ranking rows from large tables using FULLTEXT is very slow

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, sql-order-by, query-optimization

When we log into our database with mysql-client and launch these queries:

first test query:

```
select a.* 
  from ads a  
 inner join searchs_titles s on s.id_ad = a.id 
 where match(s.label) against ('"bmw serie 3"' in boolean mode) 
 order by a.ranking asc limit 0, 10;
```

The result is:

```
10 rows in set (1 min 5.37 sec)
```

second test query:

```
select a.*
  from ads a  
 inner join searchs_titles s on s.id_ad = a.id 
 where match(s.label) against ('"ford mondeo"' in boolean mode) 
 order by a.ranking asc limit 0, 10;
```

The result is:

```
10 rows in set (2 min 13.88 sec)
```

These queries are too slow. Is there a way to improve this?

The 'ads' table contains 2 millions rows, triggers are set to duplicate the data into search title. Search titles contains the id, title and label of each row in ads.
Table 'ads' is powered by innoDB and 'searchs_titles' by myISAM with a fulltext index on the label field.

Do we have too many columns? Too many indexes? Too many rows?
Is it a bad query?

Thanks a lot for the time you will spend helping us!

[image]

[image]

Edit: add explain

```
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys        | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | fulltext | id_ad,label          | label   | 0       |                  |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref   | PRIMARY,id,id_2,id_3 | PRIMARY | 4       | XXXXXX.s.id_ad |    1 |                                              |
```

Comment: You mean instead of requesting a.* we should request a.the specifics indexed columns?

Comment: The screenshots are not readable. Do you have a fulltext index on searchs_titles.label?

Comment: Can you show a explain plan of the query? Since this an optimization question, this info is fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro tip: Never use `*` in a `SELECT` statement in production software (unless you have a very good reason). By asking for all columns, you are denying the optimizer access to information about how best to exploit your indexes.

Observation: you're ordering by `ads.ranking` and taking ten results. But `ads.ranking` has very low cardinality -- according to that image in your question, it has 26 distinct values. Is your query working correctly?

Observation: You've said that the fulltext part of your search takes .77 seconds. I mean this part:

```
select s.id 
  from searchs_titles AS s
 where match(s.label) against ('"ford mondeo"' in boolean mode)
```

That is good. It means we can focus on the rest of the query.

You also said you've been testing with the insertions to the table turned off. That's good because it rules out contention as a cause for the slow queries.

Suggestion: Create a suitable compound index for `ads`.  For your present query, try an index on `(id, ranking)`  This may allow your `ORDER BY` operation to avoid a full table scan.

Then, try this query to extract the set of ten `a.id` values you need, and then retrieve the data rows. This will exploit your compound index.

```
select z.*  
  from ads AS z
  join ( select a.id, a.ranking
           from ads AS a
          inner join searchs_titles s on s.id_ad = a.id 
          where match(s.label) against ('"ford mondeo"' in boolean mode) 
          order by a.ranking asc 
          limit 0, 10
        ) AS b ON z.id = b.id
 order by z.ranking
```

This uses a subquery to do the `order by ... limit ...` datashuffling operation on a small subset of the columns. This should make the retrieval of the appropriate id values much faster. Then the outer query fetches the appropriate rows.

The bottom line is this:  `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` can be a very expensive operation if it's done on lots of data. But if you can arrange for it to be done on a minimal choice of columns, and those columns are indexed correctly, it can be very fast.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience and knowledge with us, we are all junior here :), to answer your first question it takes 0.77 sec on different keywords not cached I think its quick! second question: currently no load into this database we have stopped the workers inserting / updating data into it. should we use our repplica to do only select and use our master for insert/update? thanks again I will try your suggestion and keep you informed

Comment: try the compound index on `ads`. And try my nested query, to fetch the ads.id values from the compound index, and then hit the main table for just ten rows.  0.77 seconds for fulltext search is really quite good.

Comment: Let's address questions of replicas after you fix this > 60 sec query.

Comment: Thanx a lot! queries are really fast now, less than 0.50! I reset the cache with sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && reset query cache to be sure! thanks again!

Comment: That's great! For the benefit of others, what exactly did you do?  The subquery to retrieve the IDs? The compound index? Please let us know.

Comment: I used the subquery :) and I only took the columns we needed

Comment: forgot to say that I also used compound indexes on the needed columns